# Duda con un PreparedStatement que ejecuta un UPDATE

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statements

Tengo este `PreparedStatement`, me gustaría saber si esta correcto, también me gustaría saber si se tiene que crear un método para hacer el `EXECUTE`, o en el mismo método del `PreparedStatement` del `UPDATE`.

```
public void Modify(int id_estado_operacion, Date fechaHora_publicacion,  Date audit_fechaHora_ultima_modificacion, int id_publicacion) {
  Connection connection = null;
  PreparedStatement prepareStmt = null;

  try{
      String query = "update publicaciones set id_estado_operacion,"
            + "fechaHora_publicacion=?, "
            + "adudit_fechaHora_ultima_modificacion=GETDATE() "
            + "where id_publicacion = ? ";

      prepareStmt.setInt(0,id_estado_operacion);
      prepareStmt.setDate(1,fechaHora_publicacion);
      prepareStmt.setDate(2,audit_fechaHora_ultima_modificacion );
      prepareStmt.setInt(3,id_publicacion);
      prepareStmt.executeUpdate();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: Este código te dará al menos dos errores: 1º. No estás creando en ningún momento el objeto `prepareStmt`. Según el código siempre será nulo. Para crearlo, debes hacer algo así: `prepareStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);`. Luego, cuando seteas cada valor, como dice Luiggi, debes empezar por el  uno (1). 2º. Ahí mismo tienes otro error, en la consulta preparada tienes sólo dos `?` y estás seteando cuatro valores. La sintaxis de la consulta no parece ser correcta... `set id_estado_operacion,` ¿?  y luego esto tampoco tiene mucho sentido: `adudit_fechaHora_ultima_modificacion=GETDATE()`

Comment: También tu objeto `connection` debe ser válido. En el código no se ve en qué momento se establece la conexión. Quizá deberías revisar [la documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) sobre el asunto.

Comment: a ok si de eso ya lo hize no lo puse en el codigo pero si lo ralize muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que JDBC trabaja con los índices en base a 1, no a 0. Los parámetros deberías colocarlos desde el índice 1.

Tu código debería cambiar a esto:

```
prepareStmt.setInt(1,id_estado_operacion);
prepareStmt.setDate(2,fechaHora_publicacion);
prepareStmt.setDate(3,audit_fechaHora_ultima_modificacion );
prepareStmt.setInt(4,id_publicacion);
prepareStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: gracias , mi pregunta ahora es como se hace el EXute de este SP

Comment: @NymHaRI usando `prepareStmt#executeUpdate` debería ejecutarse tu sentencia de lado de la base de datos. Eso debería ser suficiente.